# Two users on same database giving different performance while running same test-case

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have Oracle 11gR2 database. It has two users User1 and User2. We are seeing around 2 time degradation for User2 while running same test-case. Schema, records are same for these two different users.

Query to `dba_users` shows that both use same default tablespace` and temporary tablespace.

Can someone please elaborate on what other parameters I can check and how to do that?

Comment: Check both schema's have up to date statistics otherwise the query execution paths could be different between them causing your performance issues.

Comment: Just guessing - were the tests run one after the other, with User2 going first and then User1?  If so, it might be that the data had to be read from disk by User2, but was then cached in memory when the same tests were run by User1.

Comment: Tests were run not once but several times (sometimes consecutively sometimes one after another in no particular order). This I believe will eliminate the impact of caches.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a RAC? if so, then they might be coming in on two separate machines.
Also, what network is involved for the 2 users (i.e. is one on the LAN and the other on the WAN)?

Comment: No, it is not RAC. Tests related to both users were run on same box and the DB is also on the same box.